# use ExecutorService occur out of memory on android

Tags: android

I use ExecutorService. but sometimes occur `OutOfMemoryError`

error log.

```
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
   at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
   at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.m4m.domain.CapturePipeline.executeProcessor(CapturePipeline.java:195)
   at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.m4m.domain.CapturePipeline.start(CapturePipeline.java:156)
   at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.record.VideoCapture.start(VideoCapture.java:92)
   at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.record.Capturing.startCapturing(Capturing.java:97)
   at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.record.RecTimerHandler.startRecording(RecTimerHandler.java:221)
   at kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid.record.RecTimerHandler.handleMessage(RecTimerHandler.java:83)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
```

and my source

```
protected ExecutorService pools;

public void start() {
   pools = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

   executeProcessor();
}

protected void executeProcessor() {
    pools.execute(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
         ...
         }
    }
}
```

first, `pools = Executors.newCachedTheadPool();`   previously `pools = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

usually, this situation. how to fix `OutOfMemory` when I use `ExecutorService` on android?

if you know this problem. please advice for me

thanks

Comment: What does the method `run` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cachedThreadPoolExecutor() will create a potentially unbounded (infinite) number of threads given new tasks. I am not sure what you have included in you `run()` method, however if it has a `for loop/while loop` or any other mechanism that spawns new work, it will automatically create a new thread costing you memory. This is what could potentially lead you to the `OutOfMemoryException` you are receiving.

To diagnose, try using a `fixedThreadPool(int numOfThreads)` with a low (bounded) number of threads e.g. 4 and see if you still get the error.

1. If yes, then consider what the run method is doing to consume memory
2. If no, then you now know that the number of threads the `cachedThreadPoolExecutor()` was creating was problematic, try decompose your tasks to use fewer threads. Try finding that sweet spot of thread count/ memory usage/ performance , this kind of stuff is usually about management and there rarely is a one-size fits all approach.

Comment: A single thread executor will only create one new thread in the background, . The work in the `run()` method will execute sequentially however. If this is fine for your use case then go ahead. May I ask what kind of work you are doing in the `run()` . This strategy is good if you don't want memory overhead (assuming the run() method isn't memory intensive), also if the work you are doing is heavy on computation not IO, and if you are worried about concurrency issues

Comment: If you are doing a lot of I/O work e.g. reading network/from disk/camera/microphone at the same time, I would recommend using a `fixedThreadPoolExecutor(number of threads)` each thread to handle those individual tasks